# Going from clustered environment with named SQL instance to single VM server with the default instance but

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to keep the original named instance name.  Nearly a decade ago, a contractor set up our clustered environment (Svr1 and Svr2) and installed SQL Enterprise on it for its failover capabilities, creating a named instance - MELDSQL

We need to replace the hardware and have created a VM server with SQL Server to test the environment.  The VM server (say 'NewVMSvr') has a default SQL instance on it called NewVMSvr.

Problem is, in the ensuing 10 years, a whole host of hooks have been built using MELDSQL as the reference.  Changing those would be a task outside of the possible project scope.

What I'd like to do is turn off the MELDSQL cluster (Svr1 and 2) and rename NewVMSvr to MELDSQL.  We've determined that our AD has no record of the value "MELDSQL".

According to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c07ab906-dabf-4303-9737-d430d82c4f42/how-to-rename-instance-of-sql-server-2008-r2
renaming a default instance would appear to be pretty straight forward.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused. Is MELDSQL a virtual cluster name with default SQL instance? 
There is named instance example COMPUTERNAME\InstanceName. 
If MELDSQL is a virtual name then there is DNS record for it and you can ping MELDSQL.
In this case you have to rename NewVMSvr to MELDSQL and change SQL name as it described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx

If you have COMPUTERNAME\MELDSQL then it is a different story. Please make it clear.